# R 3.4.2 | "some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'"

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to plot some data on a histogram using R so I can make a Chi Squared Test on it later. I was told to use some specific breaks on the histogram, but when I use it, I get the error on the title. Here's the code:

```
aux = hist(x, freq=F, col='lightblue', breaks=c(50, 150, 200, 1500))
hist(x, nclass=15, freq=F, col='lightblue')
```

The length of the dataset is 59 and the maximum value is 1286.137. I've already done this before without problem, with another dataset en different breaks, so I don't know what could be causing the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: if there are only 59 entries then editing your question to include the output from `dput(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your minimum value is less than 50. Try:

```
aux = hist(x, freq=F, col='lightblue', breaks=c(min(x), 150, 200, 1500))
```